# Django model inheritance problem. How to solve?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, django-orm

I have an existing app with the following model

```
class Contact(models.Model):
     lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     ...

class Journalist(Contact):
     pass
```

I have a `Contact` in my database and I would like that it becomes a `Journalist`.

In raw sql, it seems as simple as `insert into app_journalist values (25624);`. In this example 25624 is the id of the existing contact. It seems to work ok and the django app seems happy.

However, I would like to make the same thing with the django ORM. I have tried several thinks like forcing the journalist id (`Journalist(id=25624)`) but it creates a new contact rather than linking to the existing one.

Is it possible do to that with the Django ORM? How?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is (without changing your model structure) to set the `contact_ptr` attribute of the `Journalist` instance to the appropriate `Contact` instance. For e.g.

```
contact = Contact.objects.get(pk = 25624)
journalist = Journalist(contact_ptr = contact)
journalist.save()
```

This becomes easier to understand if you first look at the table `app_journalist`. It has but one column, `contact_ptr_id`. So when you execute `insert into app_journalist values (25624)` you are setting `contact_ptr_id = 25624` at the SQL level. Correspondingly you should set the  `contact_ptr = <instance of Contact>` at the ORM level.

**Update**

There are other ways to solve the problem but they would require changes to your existing models. As @bugspy.net [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871094/django-model-inheritance-problem-how-to-solve/3871325#3871325) you can use a generic relationship. Alternately you can declare an additional `type` field to specify whether the contact is a journalist, a colleague etc.

**Update 2**

Also take a look at this [demo snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2216/) (and the [complete code](http://gist.github.com/608595)) that lets you use *polymorphic inheritance* (SQLAlchemy already does this).

**Update 3**

As @luc himself pointed out (see comment below)

```
journalist = Journalist(contact_ptr = contact)
```

alone will not suffice. This will overwrite the `firstname` and `lastname` of the `contact` to `""`. To avoid this you have to explicitly assign each field to `Journalist`.

Comment: It seems that this is not enough because the lastname and firstname of the contact are overwritten with empty values. It seems that I also have to copy field by field.

for a in contact.__dict__:
    if a != '_state':
        journalist.__dict__[a] = contact.__dict__[a]

Anyway, thanks for your precious help

Answer (score 2):

Django's [Contenttypes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) framework is really handy.
You could use it to represent different contact types:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Contact(models.Model):
     lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance at the model level is usually not such a good idea. Most ORM let you do it. Most ORM are even proud to be able to do it. At the model level, the famous "[prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)" is more true than ever.

In your case, instead of saying : *"A journalist IS A person"*, you could instead say : *"A person has a job, which in this case is journalist"*. This would be represented by a Person class composed with a Job class. One of the job could be "journalist".

The composition approach lets you have a person change job, or even have multiple jobs.

Of course, this doesnt directly answer your question, but the other answers are already pretty good !

Comment: I agree with you but it is an existing application and changing the model will not be easy